# Is any simple abelian variety covered by a non-simple abelian variety

Tags: abelian-varieties, arithmetic-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A/k$ be a simple abelian variety.

Does there exist a non-simple abelian variety $B/k$ and a finite homomorphism $f:B\to A$ over $k$?

I don't need $f:B\to A$ to be etale.

Comment: I believe the question should truly be "Is any simple abelian variety covered by a non-simple abelian variety?"

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Thanks for correcting my English.

Comment: It isn't necessarily a question of English, more of mathematics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. If $End_A$ and $End_B$ are the endomorphism rings then an isogeny $B\to A$ will give an isomorphism $End_A\otimes\mathbb Q\to End_B\otimes\mathbb Q$. But the first of these algebras is a division algebra and the second is not.

Comment: In case this wasn't clear: a finite homomorphism is necessarily etale since if it etale over one point it is etale over every point, and finite morphisms are etale on a nonempty open subset, thus it is an isogeny.

Comment: To elaborate: If $f:B\to A$ is finite and separable (e.g. if $char\, k=0$) then Riemann-Hurwitz implies that the ramification divisor $R= K_A-f^*K_B=0$. Therefore $f$ is etale.